# Can a docker image be redistributed after it is downloaded from private docker registry?

Tags: linux, docker, security, dockerfile, docker-secrets

I have a docker image and I have to distribute image using private registry but is it possible to redistribute the image after pulling on the local machine?

If yes, Is there any way we can provide isolation so that the client cannot redistribute it?

Comment: yes, it's possible de tag the image and push it to another registry

Comment: Stuff in Docker generally cannot "be secured": the operator running it has unrestricted root access over the host, and can easily see the contents of images and containers and copy them around as much as they'd like.

Comment: @DavidMaze is there some way we can restrict root access?

Comment: No.  An operator can always `docker run -u 0` to get a root shell or manually pull files out of `/var/lib/docker`, and an operator can always `docker run -v/:/host busybox vi /host/etc/sudoers` to give themselves root if they don't have it yet.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it's possible de tag the image and push it to another register. It's not possible to avoid redistribute it. If you have data to protect, try to use `volumes, secret, configs`.

Comment: Thanks, I will work on suggestions.

Comment: But I have read that volumes can be distributed, am I correct?